# BlockingCollection<T>.TakeFromAny, for collections with a different generic type

Tags: c#, generics, task-parallel-library, blockingcollection

There is a [`BlockingCollection<T>.TakeFromAny`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267247(v=vs.110).aspx) method in .NET. It first tries a fast-acquire Take and then defaults to a 'slow' method waiting on underlying Handles. I would like to use this to listen to both upstream producers supplying "Messages" and downstream producers supplying "Results".

- Can TakeFromAny be used - or is there another way, without re-implementation of such - to listen for additions to a collection of heterogeneously-typed Blocking Collections?

The following code is *not* type-valid and naturally fails to compile:

```
object anyValue;
var collection = new List<BlockingCollection<object>>();
// following fails: cannot convert
//    from 'System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<Message>'
//    to 'System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<object>'
collection.Add(new BlockingCollection<Message>());
// fails for same reason
collection.Add(new BlockingCollection<Result>());
BlockingCollection<object>.TakeFromAny(collection.ToArray(), out anyValue);
```

It would be possible to deal only with `new BlockingCollection<object>()` instances and cast on Take to avoid the compilation type error, although such rubs me wrong(er) - especially because the typing is lost through the method interfaces. Using a wrapping composition type would solve the latter; fsvo 'solve'.

---

Nothing below here is directly related to the question, although it provides context - for those who are interested. Higher level constructs (eg. Rx or TPL Dataflow) are not available to the code which is providing core infrastructure functionality.

Here is a a basic flow model. The producer, proxy, and workers run on separate threads (the workers could run on the same thread, depending on what the task scheduler does).

```
[producer]   message -->   [proxy]   message --> [worker 1]
             <-- results             <-- results
                                     message --> [worker N..]
                                     <-- results
```

The expectation is the proxy listens for Messages (incoming) and Results (going back out). The proxy does some work such as transformation and grouping and it uses the results as feedback.

Having the proxy as a separate thread isolates it from the initial production source which does all sorts of monkey business. The worker tasks are for parallelism, not asynchronicity, and threading (after the contention is reduced/eliminated though the grouping in the proxy) should allow good scaling.

The queues are established between the proxy and workers (instead of direct tasks with a single input/result) because, while a worker is executing, there may be additional incoming work messages that it can process before it ends. This is to ensure the worker can prolong/reuse the contexts it establishes over a stream of related work.

Comment: 1. Is it okay to block a thread for each collection? 2. Do you need a guaranteed "take only from one collection" operation, or is it more like "i want to process all items in both collections, but I don't want to do it in parallel"?

Comment: @svick The upstream producer (writing on the 'message' queue) and fanned-out downstream consumers/producers (they produce a result on the 'result' queue) can be blocked - this 'proxy' consumer/producer runs in a separate thread context from any other processing and moves the messages from upstream, to the downstream consumers after a transformation, and moves the result back upstream using it as feedback. The goal is to 'wait for the next thing to do', from any queue, do it, and then wait some more.

Comment: @svick I suppose my initial thought/design is for "a poll/select, using typed blocking collections".

Comment: @svick Or, "poor man's version of actors"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best option here is to change the type of both blocking collections to `BlockingCollection<object>`, which you already mentioned, including its cons.

If you can't or don't want to do that, another solution would be to have a merged `BlockingCollection<object>` and a thread for each source collection that moves items from its collection to the merged one:

```
var producerCollection = new BlockingCollection<Message>();
var consumerCollection = new BlockingCollection<Results>();

var combinedCollection = new BlockingCollection<object>();

var producerCombiner = Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var item in producerCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        combinedCollection.Add(item);
    }
});

var consumerCombiner = Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var item in consumerCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        combinedCollection.Add(item);
    }
});

Task.WhenAll(producerCombiner, consumerCombiner)
    .ContinueWith(_ => combinedCollection.CompleteAdding());

foreach (var item in combinedCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    // process item here
}
```

It's not very efficient, since it blocks two additional threads just to do this, but it's the best alternative I could think of without using reflection to get access to the handles used by `TakeFromAny`.

Comment: I decided to go with the `BlockingCollection<object>` route with more guarded access. In the process I discovered that TakeFromAny is quite biased. It will always favor first collections (if they have a quick take, or on the slow take if multiple wait handles signal at the same time).